# Hello! is that anyway to write similar query without using union?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, pivot, query-optimization

is that anyway to write similar query without using union?

```
select sum(decode(p.sumsend,0,1,0)) recvcnt,
       sum(decode(p.sumsend,0,1,0)*p.sumserv) recvsum
  from some_table p
 where p.polefilter = 5
 union
select sum(decode(p.sumsend,0,1,0)) recvcnt,
       sum(decode(p.sumsend,0,1,0)*p.sumserv) recvsum
  from some_table p
 where p.polefilter != 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with having all 4 columns on one row, then one option is conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(case when polefilter =  5 and sumsend = 0 then 1 else 0 end) recvcnt1,
    sum(case when polefilter =  5 and sumsend = 0 then 1 else 0 end *  sumserv) recvsum1,
    sum(case when polefilter <> 5 and sumsend = 0 then 1 else 0 end) recvcnt2,
    sum(case when polefilter <> 5 and sumsend = 0 then 1 else 0 end *  sumserv) recvsum2
from some_table p
where polefilter is not null
```

On the other hand, if you want two rows in the resultset, then you can use aggregation and a `case` expression to define the groups:

```
select 
    case when polefilter = 5 then 1 else 0 end as polefilter_is_5
    sum(case when sumsend = 0 then 1 else 0 end) recvcnt,
    sum(case when sumsend = 0 then 1 else 0 end *  sumserv) recvsum1
from some_table p
where p.polefilter is not null
group by case when polefilter = 5 then 1 else 0 end
```

Note that I changed the `decode()` functions to `case` expressions; both do the same thing, but the latest is standard SQL (and is somehow more flexible).

Answer (score 0):

A query like the one below should work. Please provide sample data and expected output when asking a question next time.

```
  SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN p.sumsend = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                 recvcnt,
         SUM (CASE WHEN p.sumsend = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * p.sumserv)     recvsum
    FROM some_table p
GROUP BY CASE p.polefilter WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```